# Find specific folder path in s3 bucket

Tags: awk, command-line, grep, amazon-s3

I'm searching a folder in s3 bucket using this command

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/dir1/dir2/dir3 --recursive | grep -i 'dir3'
```

It's getting results like

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/1/aaa.txt 
dir1/dir2/dir3/1/bbb.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/1/ccc.txt
```

However, I need only path of that file like

```
dir1/dir2/dir3
```

I can able remove unnecessary text to get directory path by this

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/dir1/dir2/dir3 --recursive | grep -i 'dir2' | head -n 1 | sed 's/1.*//'
```

But this is not working with multiple string search in grep

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/dir1/dir2/dir3 --recursive | grep -i 'dir3\|folder3'
```

I need output like this

```
dir1/dir2/dir3
folder1/folder2/folder3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
for i in `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/dir1/dir2/dir3 --recursive | grep -i 'dir3' `
do
dirname $i >>/tmp/file
done
sort -u /tmp/file >/tmp/file1
```

And on the end you will have the list of subdirectories in file `/tmp/file1`

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the filenames from the end of each path with a `sed` operation. You can then remove adjacent duplicates with `uniq`, or if duplicates occur that are not adjacent use `sort -u`.

The result can then be searched as required,

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/dir1/dir2/dir3 --recursive |
    sed 's![^/]*$!!' |
    uniq |
    grep -Ewi 'dir3|folder1'
```